# Capitalization in "the University has 1000s of students. "

Tags: nouns, orthography, capitalization

> The University of London is huge. The **U**niversity/**u**niversity has 1000s of students.

Is it correct to leave out the capital *u* in the second sentence?

Comment: I found conflicting responses to this same query, although not in regard to the University of London specifically. For example, the University of Texas at Austin requires the use of a capital even when not using Texas or Austin, but the University of Colorado says to never use a capital unless also using Colorado. I could not find a definitive answer as to when I should capitalize university when referring to a specific university but not using the name of its location. For example, if I am at the University of Arizona, am I at the University or the university when I leave off the Arizona in w

Comment: @DanMorenoJr Precisely: there is no definitive answer. This is a matter of style, and so the careful writer should adhere to the discipline of his or her editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, observe the guidance of whichever [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/16052) is preferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The University of London itself seems to think it is required. Its website has this final paragraph on its [About Us page](http://www.london.ac.uk/aboutus.html):

> As well as offering a world class education the University has a range
>   of other services on offer including a careers service, data archiving
>   and networking, library services, conference facilities and you can
>   even use University buildings for location filming.

The justification for this is that it is the University of London, and not any old university, that is being referred to.

Comment: Thanks Barrie - but is it correct to also leave it out? Because in my mind its not the actual name of the university or its official title; thanks for the input.

Comment: Forget 'correct'. If you think you can justify a lower case 'u' to any critics, then use it.

Comment: I suspect it's not the UoL's 'thinking' the need for a capital 'U'. In the 'About Us' page, *University* with a capital 'U', or with the definite article, refers by default  to the University of London. Any occurrence of the word with a lowercase 'u' would refer to university in general. This is the standard/ conventional style.

Comment: @Kris: Yes, you can see _University_ there as a shortened form of _University of London_. On the other hand, there may be those who see _university_ as generic, and hence with a lower case first letter, much as would be the case had it read _the **establishment** has a range of other services . . . and you can even use **establishment’s** buildings for location filming_.

Comment: This reminds me of how the OED when referring to itself uses “this Dictionary”.

Comment: @tchrist: So it does. Hadn't noticed before, but here's an example: _More revised entries are added to the online Dictionary every quarter_.